# Binary files in Gridfs-Mongo DB to be stored in local drive in python 2.7

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, mapi, gridfs

I have stored some attachments into GridFS mongo using the Put command in Gridfs.

x12 = 'c:\test\' + str10 
attachment.SaveAsFile(x12)
with open(x12, 'rb') as content_file:
   content = content_file.read()

object_id = fs.put(strattach,filename=str10) 
strattach is obtained as follows 
attachment = A1.Item(1) processing email attachments using MAPI
strattach = str(attachment) converting to string.If i am not doing this i get a Typeerror: saying
can only write strings or file like objects

A1 is the attachments collection and attachment is the object obtained.
Now the Put was successful and i got the the object ID object_id which was store in Mongo db along with file name.

Now i need to build my Binary file again using the object_id and file name in Python 2.7.

to do this i read from gridfs using f2 = object_id.read() and tried to apply the write method on F2
which is failing. When i read the manual it said read in python 2.7 returns a string instance.

Could you please help me on how i can save that instance back as a binary file in python2.7.

Any alternate suggestions will also be helpful

Thanks

Comment: I could fix this issue.